# What should I name such a to-do list?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

I'm confused about the name of one list in my to-do lists. In this list, I want to include *important things that belong to quite different categories and happen irregularly or only once*. For example, I may go to the supermarket this Saturday or Sunday, depending on when the rain stops. Also, I have to buy the laboratory a new table before the end of this semester. These things are not trivial and must be done sometime. But I'm not sure when I will do them, so I want to list them together and give them a name to remind myself. Are there any words or short phrases that fit them? Thanks!

Comment: Just name them *errands* and call it a day. That's what I do.

Answer (score 2):

Call it **Misc**, short for **miscellaneous**, and meaning "unrelated collection".

*consisting of various kinds of people or things* – [macmillandictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/miscellaneous#miscellaneous_3)

*consisting of diverse things or members* – [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miscellaneous)

*of various types or from different sources* – [oxforddictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/miscellaneous)

Comment: Hi Martin. This is a promising start, but it's not complete. On EL&U we're looking for answers that are *detailed and definitive*. Can you add some value to your post, for example with a linked dictionary definition? The system has flagged your post as "low-quality because of its length and content", so without extra detail it's at risk of deletion. For further guidance, see [answer].

Answer (score 1):

I often hear these sorts of things referred to as "one-off tasks."

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Note that Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers, not ideas, suggestions, or opinions. To show that yours is the right answer, please edit to include an explanation, context, and supporting facts, such as the definition from a good online dictionary. This is what makes answers useful – to the asker, and to future visitors. See: [“Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions”](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)

Answer (score 1):

You can place them under the title "When convenient/opportune/possible", or "At earliest convenience/opportunity/possibility"

Or how about make your own acronym? ASAC (As soon as convenient). Actually I did a search and it's not entirely [original](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/As+Soon+As+Convenient):

Comment: The OP says the items are "important" and "non trivial" and yet you've decided they're "of secondary importance" or of a minor nature.

Comment: @MartinF That's a good point. Time or deadline requirements, although often related to importance, are two different things. I'll delete those parts of my answer. Thank you.